# MS Access Forms resize when Modal and Popup are set to True

Tags: forms, ms-access, view

I have run into this issue several times in the past and would like to know how to resolve it.

When `Modal` and `Popup` are set to True on an MS Access 2003 Form, in what looks to be inconsistent occurrences, when the form loads, the form will be bunched up in the left hand corner of the screen. Sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't, I can't seem to pin-point what exactly is triggering the change in the form. But, once it does happen, it remains bunched up like this until the Form is put in Design mode and modified to have `.Modal = False` and `.Popup = False`

Here is an example of what the form looks like after loading it: [image: Bunched up Form]

Here is an example of what the properties are set to on the Form: [image: Form Properties]

Does anyone know why this occurs and how to prevent it while maintaining `.Modal = True` and `.Popup = True`?

Basically I require for my use case to have both `.Popup` and `.Modal` to be set to True and having the Form resize on its own volition even when the property `.BorderStyle` is changed from `Sizable` to `Dialog` is rather perplexing. Maybe I am missing something.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you think you want to use Modal and Popup? I have never used Modal (I open forms modally with the acDialog setting as needed), and only occasionally used Popup, and never used the two together. I find that they don't actually work the way they are supposed to, and that's basically why I don't use them much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say that the issue could come from `Auto Resize = No`.
Set it to `Yes` instead.

The documentation for `Form.AutoResize` says that:

> If you make any changes in Design view to a form whose AutoResize property is set to No and whose AutoCenter property is set to Yes, switch to Form view before saving the form. If you don't, Microsoft Access clips the form on the right and bottom edges the next time you open the form.

And if the `Form.AutoResize` is set to `No`:

> When opened, the Form window has the last saved size. To save a window's size, open the form, size the window, save the form by clicking Save on the File menu, and close the form or report. When you next open the form or report, it will be the saved window size.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. If you don't mind me asking, where did you get this information from?

Comment: @Curtis Inderwiesche : learnt it the hard way. I remember having issues with the right combination of these settings a while ago. For the documentation, it's the one that comes with Access itself, but you can find it [online too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb240693%28v=office.12%29.aspx)