# Why does my winform resize when i open an access database (.accdb), and how do i fix it?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, database-connection

I have a large project I am working on where opening an access database causes the whole form to shrink, after many days I have narrowed the issue down to opening an Access database (.accdb) within my project. (may also work with other databases, but I have only confirmed it with Access.

To confirm that opening the Database is the issue I created a small project with only a single button, an Open file dialog to open the database.

Here is all the code in this project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

using ADOX; //Requires Reference 'Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security' found in the reference manager under COM. Rightclick and click add reference...
using ADODB; //Requires Reference 'ADODB' found in the reference manager under assemblies. Rightclick and click add reference...

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String databaseLocation = "";
        String connectionString = "";
        String q = "";

        OleDbConnection conn = null;

        bool DatabaseOpen = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bStartLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openDB.Title = "Select Database To Load";
            openDB.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), @"Databases");
            openDB.FileName = "";
            openDB.Filter = "Access Database|*.accdb";



            try
            {

                if (openDB.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");

                }
                else {
                    databaseLocation = openDB.FileName;
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + databaseLocation + ";Persist Security Info=False";
                    conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                    conn.Open();
                    DatabaseOpen = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

To save time I have uploaded the test project to [My DropBox Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/grjmvobnlhs6249/WindowsFormsApplication3.rar?dl=0)

I have no idea why this resize is happening, my teachers have also been stumped, so maybe someone else can work it out.

NOTE: To experience the issue you need to open a .accdb database file as the issue only occurs if the database is opened and the connection has been made. conn.open(); You may also require the driver from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734 if you get an error when trying to open a database.

Comment: are you displaying anything in regards to a DataGridView .. I can't possibly see how the form gets resized after clicking on a simple button.. why don't you inspect the designer.. have you tried using the debugger to see if something else is going on..? also I doubt that anyone will down load your source code and debug this for you..

Comment: Nope, all I have done is dragged in a button and the openFile dialog, nothing else has been included, and should still be set to their default.

Comment: Might just be a visual studio 2015 bug

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351081/ms-access-forms-resize-when-modal-and-popup-are-set-to-true

Comment: Those properties don't seem to be editable in VS 2015, I also tried the suggestions mentioned there, but they didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some information on  [OleDb / OleDbConnection resizing form (bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729854/oledb-oledbconnection-resizing-form-bug) which helped me solve the issue.

It is kind of a microsoft issue, but the problem in my case was that i had installed 
2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734 as it is needed to open connections to access databases on 64bit computers, but just having that causes the resize issue and provides no errors or feedback into the issue, and as i am not directly changing the size anywhere in my form, it becomes really confusing and hard to debug.

However I also found out that also installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable (32bit)
 found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255 fixes the resize issue that occurs when opening the database.

Hopefully this helps other people in the future who are also attempting to load and save data to an access database.